# I will "be revising" "next friday" what is wrong with it?

Tags: grammar

[image]

This is a "find the mistake" question ...

> *I'll have been revised all my lessons by next Friday.

So what I did

Have been revised > be revising

So it will be "

> I'll be revising all my lessons by next Friday"

And I got it wrong .. So what is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

> I will have **revised** all my lessons by next Friday.

the pattern you want is *will have + past* since you are saying you will have *completed* it by next Friday.

> revise *(BrE)*
>   reviewed *(AmE)*
>
> I will have **reviewed** all my lessons by next Friday.
>
> I will **be revising** all my lessons by next Friday.

The second sentence does not imply being *finished* which is what the test questions seems to be asking for.